# error when reading a file with blank lines to the end

Tags: python, sockets, io

I'm trying to read a file line by line and do some stuff. The problem is that if I add a bunch of blank lines to the end of the file, I'm getting an exception (list index out of range).

```
def check_ip(address):
  try:
    socket.inet_aton(address)
    return True
  except:
    return False

def myfunction:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
        if not line: continue
        tokens = line.strip().split()
        if not check_ip( tokens[0]  ): continue
        // do some stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your empty line test doesn't take into account whitespace.

Use:

```
if not line.strip(): continue
```

otherwise you end up with an empty `tokens` list for those lines.

You don't have to call `str.strip()` when also using `str.split()` with no arguments; that call already strips leading and trailing whitespace:

```
tokens = line.split()
```

Note that you don't need (nor want) to use `f.readlines()`; you can iterate over the file object *directly*:

```
for line in f:
```

Comment: Are you sure strip() is not needed with split()? It looks like '\n' is not removed by split() alone

Comment: @Bob: `str.split()` with no arguments, or with `None` as a first argument, removes leading and trailing whitespace. So yes, I am sure.